# How to copy Build files from Jenkins server (Windows) to another windows server

Tags: .net, windows, jenkins, ssh

My Jenkin Job is building the .net sourcecode and deploying the build in Jenkin successfully . How can I configure the Jenkins to deploy the files to the web server directly .

Can publish over SSH do the job?

Comment: http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/continuous-deployment-with-jenkins-and-.net

Comment: Hi @JerryGoyal Thanks for the response . I tried to install that . But I got an error "SEVERE:Failed inspecting plugin". So my admins are skeptical to install this . Can publish over SSH do the job ???? ..